# Data structure for synonyms

Tags: ruby, database, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure to keep synonyms. I'd like "Washington D.C.", "Washington DC" or "Washington D.C" to all associate to "Washington". Something like a `List` => `Value` structure.

I have a service that sends an email to users if their city in mentioned on a specific website. When they register they enter their email and city. However some people will enter "Washington" and some others "Washington D.C.". Now I want these to be in the same "bucket" and send all of these people an email if "Washington D.C" or "Washington" is mentioned on the website.

Comment: Hashes in Ruby allow any type of object as the key, including Arrays, so your "Something like an `Array` => `Value`" is entirely possible.  Whether that's actually a useful structure depends entirely on how you intend to use it, which isn't clear.

Comment: What are your requirements? Low memory? Fast lookup? Access from any synonym to the others? What have you tried? What problems are you having with your attempts? -1 for what appears to be an ill-specified and lazy question.

Comment: I have a service that sends an email to users if their city in mentioned on a specific website. When they register they enter their email and city. However some people will enter "Washington" and some others "Washington D.C.". Now I want these to be in the same "bucket" and send all of these people an email if "Washington D.C" or "Washington" is mentioned on the website.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Synonyms
  def initialize( *syns )
    @all = []
    @idx = {}
    syns.each{ |syn| self << syn }
  end
  def <<( syn )
    p syn
    unless @idx.include?(syn)
      @all << syn
      @idx[syn] = @all  
    end
  end
  def []( syn )
    @idx[syn]
  end
end

wash = Synonyms.new "Washington DC", "Washington", "Washington D.C."

p wash["Washington"]    #=> ["Washington DC", "Washington", "Washington D.C."]
p wash["Washington DC"] #=> ["Washington DC", "Washington", "Washington D.C."]
p wash["Nope"]          #=> nil
```

Next, create a hash mapping each known synonym to its list, or loop through them, or whatever.

Comment: I guess this could work if the first element is always the "master" element which is what I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a hash of lists.

For example:

```
synonyms = {"Washington" => ["Washington D.C.", "Washington DC", "Washington D.C"], ...}
```

Then you get the benefit of the quick lookup time of a hashtable and you can iterate the items and perform list operations on them.

**UPDATE**

It sounds like what you want is still a hash. What you need to do, however, is associate any given member of a list of synonyms with a list of all other synonyms.

You could build a simple function to do this, for example:

```
def associate_synonyms(synonyms, syn_hash)
  synonyms.length.times do

    synonym = synonyms.pop

    p synonyms

    syn_hash[synonym] = synonyms.collect {|x| x}
    synonyms.insert(0, synonym)
  end
end
```

So, for example usage:

```
place = ["Washington", "Washington D.C.", "Washington DC", "Washington D.C"]
synonym_lookup = {}

associate_synonyms(place, synonym_lookup)
```

Comment: Great if the OP wants to see the synonyms for "Washington". Poor if the OP wants to see what "Washington DC" is synonymous with. This is one answer to a very underspecified question.

Comment: Sorry wasn't sure how to specify the question. What I want is actually what @Phrogz mentioned. I'd like to know what "Washington DC" is synonymous with.

Comment: Updated, is this more like what you are asking?

Comment: This will probably not be an effective solution, I reckon. Reason is that, the algorithm has to check every such list in the dictionary, i.e for every city, until it finds a list that contains the matching word. After which the key value will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarified needs, the simplest solution would probably be a simple Hash, where each possible synonym simply points to the canonical city name:

```
city_name_map = {"Washington D.C." => "Washington",
                 "Washington DC"   => "Washington",
                 "Washington D.C"  => "Washington",
                 "Washington"      => "Washington",
                 # and so forth
                }
```

When people sign up with `"Washington D.C."`, their city preference in the database is stored as the value of `city_name_map["Washington D.C."]`, which is `"Washington"`.  Similarly when searching pages for city mentions, just check the map for the canonical name of the city.  If a website mentions `"Washington DC"`, you look it up and get `"Washington"`, and then contact people whose canonical city preference matches.

Comment: I think that's the easiest solution. Thanks

Comment: But this will be space ineffective when your number of cities will keep increasing. I am not sure. I think so.